# Meta data file size changeable

Tags: windows, storage, metadata

I recently learned about metadata and how its information about the data itself.
Seeing how file size includes among those statistics would it be possible to change the file size to something absurd and unreasonable like 1000 petabytes; in this case, you can what would the effects be on a computer and how would it affect a windows 11 computer?

Answer (score 0):

Not all metadata is directly editable.  Some of it are simply properties of the file.  You can't just set the file size to an arbitrary number, you have to actually edit the file itself.  So to create a 1,000 petabytes file, you need to have that much disk space first.

Another example would by the file type.  You can't change a jpeg into a png by setting `filetype=png`.  You have to process and convert the file, giving you an entirely new and different file with it's own set of metadata/properties.